# Редактирование QTableView

Tags: qt, qt5

Привет! Создал таблицу QTableView на форме следующим образом:

```
QTableView *table = new QTableView(this);
table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::AllEditTriggers);
```

Вроде установил триггеры на редактирование таблицы, но сделать это все равно не получается. Как сделать так, чтобы ячейки можно было редактировать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виджеты, содержащие в наименовании класса `Q...View`, предназначены для работы с подключаемыми извне моделями. То есть для `QTableView`, `QTreeView` и `QListView` потребуется предварительно создать модель:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(4,4,this);
for(int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 4; ++col) {
        QStandardItem *item
            = new QStandardItem(QString("row %0, col %1")
                .arg(row).arg(col));

        model->setItem(row, col, item);
    }
}

QTableView *table = new QTableView(this);
table->setModel(model);

QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView(this);
tree->setModel(model);

QListView *list = new QListView(this);
list->setModel(model);
```

*К слову, в этом примере одна модель будет доступна сразу трём виджетам, и во всех из них её возможно будет редактировать.*

Для случаев, когда использование внешней модели избыточно, нужно создавать виджеты, содержащие в наименовании классов `Q...Widget`. Это экономит время, поскольку модель в этих классах (`QTableWidget`, `QTreeWidget` и `QListWidget`) уже встроена.

```
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(4,4,this);
table->show();

QTreeWidget *tree = new QTreeWidget(this);
tree->setColumnCount(1);
tree->show();

{
    QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        QStringList list;
        list.append(QString("item: %1").arg(i));

        items.append(new QTreeWidgetItem(list));
    }

    tree->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);
}

QListWidget *list = new QListWidget(this);
new QListWidgetItem("1", list);
new QListWidgetItem("2", list);
new QListWidgetItem("3", list);
list->show();
```

Comment: Забыл упомянуть что использую QSqlQueryModel. Проблема заключается в том, что я никак не могу редактировать ячейку, т.е. нажав на нее ничего не происходит, даже дабл кликом (в самой таблице)

Comment: `QSqlQueryModel` не позволяет редактировать данные. Используйте `QSqlTableModel`.

Comment: Как стоит построить работу, если данные для таблицы вытаскиваю SQL запросом? Переводить его в модель будет довольно долго, так как записей очень много (>100000 записей)

Comment: Решить можно различно, начиная от использования представлений (view) на уровне БД и заканчивая экспортом данных из `QSqlQueryModel` в иную модель (не обязательно SQL), поддерживающую редактирование. Если записей так много, то в виджет их всех для редактирования загонять ни в коем случае нельзя. Как минимум у Вас должно поддерживаться лимитирование, а проще говоря постраничность. Но это всё отдельная большая тема и для текущего вопроса является оффтопиком.

Comment: Благодарю за совет, сам принцип лимитирования понял, но даже не представляю как сделать удобный интерфейс. Не могли бы немного в сторону представлений направить?

Comment: Если по mysql, то вот такое на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/47031/). Но представления удобны в том случае, если в запросе используется, например, множество `join`'ов. Если же задача стоит на уровне лимитирования кол-ва строк, то здесь только постраничность, представления ничего, по идее, не дадут.